# Ghostscript - Wrong CMYK Color Conversion - 100% Yellow convert to 98% Yellow?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, tiff, ghostscript, cmyk

I try to convert a **CMYK .pdf** as **CMYK .tif** with the good **CMYK percentages**.

But i've a **strange color conversion**.

### Colors:

Look some converted color to understand the "strange" conversion:

**100% yellow** in pdf was converted as **98% yellow** the TIF:

```
PDF = C:0 M:0 Y:100 K:0
TIF = C:0 M:0 Y:98  K:0
```

**100% Magenta** in pdf was converted as **1C/100M/1Y** the TIF:

```
PDF = C:0 M:100 Y:0 K:0
TIF = C:1 M:100 Y:1  K:0
```

**black is good** (and all gray tone like 10%,20%...):

```
PDF = C:0 M:0 Y:0 K:100
TIF = C:0 M:0 Y:0  K:100
```

but **full 100** is **not good** !?:

```
PDF = C:100 M:100 Y:100 K:100
TIF = C:73 M:68 Y:66  K:89
```

and a **C100/M20 wrong** too (pdf total **120** tif total **121** ?):

```
PDF = C:100 M:20 Y:0 K:0
TIF = C:99 M:21 Y:1  K:0
```

### files:

download the source PDF: 
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byc9qwtxxi1dSlo2eHJxM1hpMU0/view?usp=sharing][1]

download the converted TIF: 
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byc9qwtxxi1dVWN6NWlBUEF0Z2c/view?usp=sharing][2]

> !!!Attention: Open the files in photoshop to correctly preview the
>   color and use the color picker to compare the value of each colors.

### Cmd:

I search on google and read all the ghostscript doc since 2 weeks, and that's my best cmd :

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER 
-sDEVICE=tiff32nc
-sDeviceNProfile 
-dKPreserve=2 
-dRenderIntent=1 
-dCOLORSCREEN=false 
-dNOINTERPOLATE 
-dUseCIEColor 
-dNOTRANSPARENCY 
-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 
-dTextAlphaBits=4 
-dFirstPage=1 
-dLastPage=1 
-r600 
-sOutputICCProfile=USwebCoatedSOWPv2.icc 
-sOutputFile=CMYK.tif
CMYK.pdf
```

(Unix Ghostscript 9.10)

### Doc:

http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.10/GS9_Color_Management.pdf
http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Devices.htm#PDF

### ???

What do you think ? is a bug or a wrong cmd !?
Did anyone else have this experience?

Thanks,

## UPDATE 1

I reduce the cmd at his minimal :

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER 
-sDEVICE=tiffsep 
-dKPreserve=2 
-sOutputFile=CMYK.tif 
-r300 
-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 
-dTextAlphaBits=4 
-dFirstPage=1 
-dLastPage=1 
CMYK.pdf
```

And have the same wrong color convertion.

**<strike>For me, the ICC profile can't change color percents... a 100% Yellow is a 100% Yellow ! not agree?</strike>**
(in all cases, we have the same issue with or without icc profile)

## UPDATE 2

At the beginning, i can't reproduce the colors "bug" in photoshop, I thought it was ghostscript.

But i found the difference between "assign" and "convert" icc profile in photoshop.

- photoshop "assign" screencast : http://quick.as/r2jrTn4zw
- photoshop "convert" screencast : http://quick.as/xQzaHZ9xp

And it is not a bug !

## New issue

> Can't we not use the icc profile when we convert a PDF to TIF ? or use
>   globally the same profile to cancel the convert effect ?

Answer (score 0):

First, update to the current shipping version of Ghostscript. If you still think you see a problem, then open a bug report at httpss://bugs.ghostscript.com

If you open a bug please be sure to attach the specimen file, and give a complete (as simple as possible) command line to reproduce the problem. If you are using an ICC profile, you'll need to supply that as well.

By the way, I think you have a typo there as well '-sOutputICCProfile=USwebCoatedSOWPv2.icc'

Oh, and if you are intending to get decent colour management, under no circumstances should you be setting -dUseCIEColor.

I'm not clear on what you expect the CMYK values to be when you are using an ICC Profile to correct the output, you surely aren't expecting them to be unchanged ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the last Ghostscript version to compare. But i only use 9.10 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS ! not ?

Comment: By the way, I don't agree with your statement that using an ICC profile can't change the % of a colourant. That is the *point* of a colour managed workflow. The colour should look the same when printed on different devices, and the ICC profile tells the Colour Management System how to modify the colourants so that they look the same given different inks and substrates.

Comment: I mean in photoshop... when i make a document 100% Yellow and i change the color profile, the 100% Yellow still 100% (http://quick.as/r2jrTn4zw). but you mean, the ghostscript make and "hard" conversion to simulate the print color like on paper ?

Comment: Okey you right ;) i find the difference between "assign" and "convert" (take a look on my  [screencast](http://quick.as/xQzaHZ9xp) ) Thank you, now, we correctly define my problem ! Can't we not use the icc profile when we convert a PDF to TIF ? or use globally the same profile to cancel the convert effect ?

Comment: You can use -dUSEFASTCOLOR which will disable the ICC workflow altogether. Or use an *input* ICC profile which produces correct output for you. You should probably read the document /ghostpdl/gs/doc/GS9_Color_Management.pdf. I'm not an expert on colour management, but I believe that using the same source and destination ICC profiles should result in no overall change.

Comment: Yes, i've already read this docs ! And try many colors management options. (the in/out ICC profile match perfect for jpeg to jpeg convertion)
I think something change the color over the ICC profile. I found this option: `-dBlackPtComp=0` it keeps my Yellow at 100%, but for exemple, the color C100 M100 Y100 K100 still change with wrong value. I make a screencast to show it quickly ! (http://quick.as/ljgyhldb8) ... and thanks for your help, the research evolves.

Comment: I *think* that if you use the same profile for input and output then the colours will remain unchanged (modulo rounding errors). If you specifically don't want to have a colour managed workflow, then set -dUSEFASTCOLOR

Comment: I already use `-dUSEFASTCOLOR` ! Maybe I write the cmd in the wrong order ? `gs -sDEVICE=tiff 32nc -dNOSUBSTDEVICECOLORS -dUSEFASTCOLOR -sOutputFile=CMYK.tif CMYK.pdf`

Comment: I continued my test ! And i note the Black and Magenta percents match all the time. It's only the Cyan and Yellow has 1% deduce ! This time, it's strange !

Answer (score 0):

I'm so close... with this tiny poorly documented option: `-dNOSUBSTDEVICECOLORS`

> gs -sDEVICE=tiff 32nc -dNOSUBSTDEVICECOLORS -sOutputFile=CMYK.tif
>   CMYK.pdf

In all of my test, the most uncatchable was the C100M100Y100K100... now is good like M100, K100, K50, M100C20, ... ! But only the Cyan100 and Yellow100 turn again on 99% !!!

I'll get it... on next...